# angular 2 undefined variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login-page',
    templateUrl: 'login-page.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

    username: string;
    password: string;
    firm: string;
    response : boolean;


    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authService: Auth, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

    }

 login(){
           let credentials = [this.username, this.password, this.firm];
           this.authService.login(credentials)
           .subscribe(
               data => this.response = data.login,
               error => alert(error),
               () => console.log("Finished")
           );
           alert(this.response);
           if(this.response){
               this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
           }else{
               alert("check your credentials");
           }
        }
```

I am trying to change the login page to home page. My rest gives me the json response like following;

`{"login":true}` --- if credentials are true

`{"login":false}` --- if credentials are false

so at this point I have two question;

1) Can I take just the boolean part of the response and set the this.response to it like in the code?

2) When I alert the response object to check its settled correctly or not, I see that response is still "undefined". I tried to set it initially to false but this line `data => this.response = data.login` does not change its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `alert(this.response);` and below is executed before the response from `authService.login()` arrives.

You need to move the code inside the callback passed to `subscribe`

```
    login(){
       let credentials = [this.username, this.password, this.firm];
       this.authService.login(credentials)
       .subscribe(
           data => {
             this.response = data.login;
               alert(this.response);
               if(this.response){
                   this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
               }else{
                   alert("check your credentials");
               }
           },
           error => alert(error),
           () => console.log("Finished")
       );
    }
```

Comment: yess man, I will definitely accept this answer but you are faster than the stackoverflow  can accept :) you should wait for couple of minutes. Thanks a lot man